# Type bounds in Scala Universe design

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I've worked with the Scala macro/reflection/compiler system on and off for a fair amount of time. One aspect has eluded my understanding: Why are all the types in [`scala.reflect.api.Universe`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Universe) (and some other places) defined using boundaries?

For example:

```
type Position >: Null <: api.Position { type Pos = Universe.this.Position }
```

or

```
type PackageDef >: Null <: Universe.PackageDefApi with Universe.MemberDef
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question to the Scala Gitter channel and received the following response (paraphrased) from Paul Phillips.

- The lower type bound `>:` on `Null` allows all of the types to be set to `null`.
- This is the public facing API of the Scala compiler system. It was created by reverse engineering pre-existing classes.